# DynamoDB Not Sorting by Sort Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, sorting, amazon-dynamodb

I'm following along in [Pluralsight's DynamoDB Deep Dive course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aws-dynamodb-deep-dive) using the AWS console. I've created a "messages" table with the following items:

[image: all dyanmodb table items]

When creating the table, the primary key was setup with a sort key:

```
Primary partition key:  |  userid (Number)
Primary sort key:       |  timestamp (Number)
```

Also, a Local Secondary Index (LSI) was added with the rating attribute as the sort key:

```
Partition key:          |  userid (Number)
Sort Key:               |  rating (Number)
```

After creating and adding *some* of the records, a Global Secondary Index (GSI) was added using the topicid & rating attributes:

```
Partition key:          |  topicid (Number)
Sort Key:               |  rating (Number)
```

When attempting to query using the GSI, and sort in descending order (by the rating sort key), the items are not in order:

[image: querying by topic id, and items out of order]

I believe I added some of the items prior to creating the GSI, and some of the items after.  All of the items have been in the table for at least 30 minutes at this point.

According to the tutorial, the items should be sorted in order of the sort (rating) field. It appears I'm missing something obvious.

---

Update:

The UI in the console seems to have changed since the tutorial. In the tutorial, a previous version of the results have no sort indicators next to the attribute names as seen here:

[image: old results table has no sort indicator next to attribute names]

Now, each attribute in the results area shows a sort indicator, as shown previously, which seems to default to the primary partition key.

Specifying sort in the query now seems to act as a secondary sort parameter after the sort selected in the results header.

A follow up question: is there a way in the AWS Console for the results to use the query's sort instead of what was last selected in the result pane heading?

Otherwise, you get the following unintuitive result when clicking "Start search" if the `rating` heading was previously clicked:

[image: sort obeys heading rather than the query's sort parameter]

Comment: The console indicates that *it* is sorting the results by userid.  What does the **ⓘ** indicate if you mouse-over it?

Comment: Wow, I completely missed that. The ⓘ simply says "Only sort items in the current page. For attributes other than partition/sort key(s), sorting in order of UTF-8 bytes is supported."